# bring div to front when clicking on link

Tags: jquery

this is what i have now: http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/833/

when you move to coloured divs around a bit you can see there are 4 links, i want each link to bring one of the divs to the foreground.

how can i do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var a = 3;
$('#box1,#box2,#box3,#box4').draggable({
start: function(event, ui) { $(this).css("z-index", a++); }
});
$('#dragZone div').click(function() {
$(this).addClass('top').removeClass('bottom');
$(this).siblings().removeClass('top').addClass('bottom');
$(this).css("z-index", a++);
});
);
```

Comment: try to play around with z-indexes http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/836/  ...the red one is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/834/

Here's the code I used:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(".top").removeClass("top").addClass("bottom");
    var box = $(this).attr("href");
    //alert(box);
    $(box).addClass("top");
    $(box).css("z-index", a++);
});
```

Comment: one more question, if i wanted to have more than one div brought to the front when clicking on a link. how would i do that? like in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/842/

Comment: I had to update quite a bit of code to pull that off... too much to put it into this comment, but you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/843/

Comment: seriously impressive, could've never figured that out! thanks so much again

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/835/

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    var x = $(this).attr('val');
    console.log(x); 
    $('#box'+x).css('z-index',a++);    
});
```

Added `class="link"` & `val='1'` attributes to `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery function to "bringToFront".

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    bringToFont: function (selector) {
        var max = Math.max.apply(null, $(this).siblings(selector).map(function () {
            return $(this).zIndex();
        }));
        $(this).zIndex(++max);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Here is an example, this code will move "#someDiv" to the top of the z-index stack.

```
$('#someDiv').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).bringToFont();
});
```